# How to calculate the side of a right triangle from the coordinates of points and the length of one side?

Tags: geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

I have the line **AB**. And I need to calculate the coordinates of point **D**.

I know the coordinates of points **A**, **B** and **C**.

If I make this an imaginary right triangle, I just need to know the length of the **CD** line (**a** in the picture)

Since I can easily calculate the line length **AC** (**d** on the picture) from the coordinates, I only need the line **AD** to calculate the **CD** using the Pythagorean theorem.

I know the coordinates of points **A** and **B**, so I can easily calculate the length of line **AB** from this.

But how do I calculate the length of the **AD** line so that I can then calculate the length of the **CD**? Or is it possible in another way? Unfortunately, I don't know the angles either.

Please help

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let $t$ the $y$ coordinate of poinr $D$. We have by simili relations that:
$$\frac{\sqrt{(x_4-x_2)^2+(t-y_2)^2}}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_4)^2+(y_1-t)^2}}=\frac{|y_3-t|}{|t-y_2|}$$
Now, you can notice that putting $O(0,0)$ on the point $A$, the points $D$ and $C$ have the same $x$ coordinate. And the equation becomes:

$$\frac{\sqrt{(x_3-x_2)^2+(t-y_2)^2}}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_3)^2+(y_1-t)^2}}=\frac{|y_3-t|}{|t-y_2|}$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. If I give a simple example A [1,1], B [11,11], C [5,1]. Here it is easy to deduce that it is D [5,5], but using your formula, I figured that [y4=6.3294](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28%285-11%29%5E2%29%2B%28%28t-11%29%5E2%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2F%28%28%28%281-5%29%5E2%29%2B%28%281-t%29%5E2%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%3D%7C%281-t%29%2F%28t-11%29%7C). What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Obtain the equation of the line (say $L$) passing through $C$ and perpendicular to the line $AC$. Calculate the point of intersection of $L$ and the line $AB$. This should give you the coordinates of $D$. In other words, if $D$ has the coordinates $(x_4,y_4)$, then you have the following constraints:

1. $(x_1-x_3)(x_4-x_3)+(y_1-y_3)(y_4-y_3)=0$. (Because $AC$ is perpendicular to $CD$)
2. $\frac{y_4-y_2}{y_2-y_1}=\frac{x_4-x_2}{x_2-x_1}$ (Because $D$ lies on $AB$. The cases where $x_1=x_2$ and/or $y_1=y_2$ can be dealt with similarly)

These can be solved to obtain $x_4,y_4$

Comment: Thanks, but there's a mistake somewhere. If I give a simple example A [1,1], B [11,11], C [5,1]. Here it is easy to deduce that it is D [5,5], but using your formula, I figured that [x4=5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-5%29*%28x4-5%29%2B%281-5%29*%28x4-5%29+%3D+0) but [y4=1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y4-1%29%2F%2811-1%29%3D%285-5%29%2F%2811-1%29) and I didn't figure out where the problem is? Am I doing something wrong or is there a mistake in the formula, please?

Comment: @yoda666 Thanks for pointing out. Apologies for my negligence. There were some typographical errors in my answer in both equations. I have edited it. Should be fine now. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, now the calculation is correct [y4 = 5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y4-11%29%2F%2811-1%29%3D%285-11%29%2F%2811-1%29). Thanks again for the simple calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This works only for Pythagorean triples or for triangles "similar" to Pythagorean triples. If $\space d \space$ is not an odd integer, round to an odd integer  greater than $\space 1 \space$and then multiply or divide all sides  (as needed) by
$\space \dfrac{d}{\text{rounded-number}}$ after the following calculations are complete.

Assuming  Pythagorean  triples where all sides are integers, we begin with the Pythagorean theorem where
$\space A^2+B^2=C^2\space $ and Euclid's formula where
$\space A=m^2-k^2 \quad B=2mk\quad C=m^2+k^2.\quad$
From your diagram we let the $x$-coordinate be $\space d=A.\quad$ For any primitiive Pythagorean triple, $\space A=2x+1, x\in\mathbb{N}\space$ and, for each $A$-value, there are
$2^{n-1}$ primitive triples where $\space n\space$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $\space A.\quad$
We can find all of these triples by solving the
$A$-function for $\space k\space$ and testing a defined range of $m$-values to see which yield integers. Note that there may be additional triples found if they are odd square multiples of primitives.

Let us begin
$$A=m^2-k^2\implies k=\sqrt{m^2-A}\\
\text{for}\qquad  \sqrt{A+1} \le m \le \frac{A+1}{2}$$
The lower limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures $m> k$.

$$A=3\cdot 5=15\implies \sqrt{15+1}=4\le m \le \frac{15+1}{2} =8\\
\text{and we find}\quad
\sqrt{4^2-15}=1,\space \sqrt{8^2-15}=7\\
i.e. \space  m\in\{4,8\}\implies k \in\{1,7\} $$
$$F(4,1)=(15,8,17)\qquad \qquad F(8,7)=(15,112,113) $$

Here, there are $2^{2-1}=2$ triples where $a=8$ or $a=112$ and $AD$ is either $17$ or $113$.

In this case,
$\space \theta\approx 28.1^\circ\space$
0r
$\space \theta\approx 82.4^\circ\space$

If you happen to know an angle, you can find the closest matching Pythagorean triple using techiques described
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265182/how-do-you-find-pythagorean-triples-that-approximately-correspond-to-a-right-tri/4270695#4270695).

Answer (score 1):

You can find angle A using cosine theorem for ABC. Then use it to find length of AD from definition of cos for triangles

Comment: I don't understand how we calculate this using a cosine theorem? This is good if I know all sides, but I don't know the angles. Or when I know only one angle and two adjacent sides. How will this help me here? Plus, in a right triangle, where can I do with the Pythagorean and Sin theorems?

Comment: You know coordinates of all points so you know all the sides of ABC, I have a typo in the answer

Comment: I already understand. For the **ABC** triangle, I know all the points. From them I calculate the length of all sides. Then I use the cosine theorem to calculate the angle at point **A**, which is the same as at triangle **ACD**. And then I use the sine theorem to calculate the length of **CD** and **AD**. And from the length of these two sides, I calculate the coordinates of point **D**. This is intuitive, but too complicated. Nevertheless, thank you for an interesting solution.